# Devise (1.0.7) authentication fails in rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

Tried to use **Devise 1.0.6** in a **Rails 2.3.5** project (I know it is bit old version). I have used instructions [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dcu-devise/1.0.7) to setup devise. Sign up is working fine but when sign in, the password field is cleared up and nothing happened. There is no error showing in log.  `admin_signed_in?` gives not signed in.

when sign in, controller create action as follows

```
  def create
    if resource = authenticate(resource_name)
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_in
      sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource, true)
    elsif [:custom, :redirect].include?(warden.result)
      throw :warden, :scope => resource_name
    else
      set_now_flash_message :alert, (warden.message || :invalid)
      clean_up_passwords(build_resource)
      render_with_scope :new
    end
  end
```

authenticate() method in model as follows

```
        def authenticate(attributes={})
          return unless authentication_keys.all? { |k| attributes[k].present? }
          conditions = attributes.slice(*authentication_keys)
          resource = find_for_authentication(conditions)
          resource if resource.try(:valid_for_authentication?, attributes)
        end
```

inspected `resource` in model and it returns a valid record. but its not reaching to controller. in controller `authenticate(resource_name)` returns `nil`

helper.rb

```
      def authenticate(scope)
        warden.authenticate(:scope => scope)
      end
```

scope is valid and `warden.authenticate(:scope => scope)` returns null .

Comment: You somehow need to give us more details...
Try to validate in rails console if the password you are using is the valid one using:
user.valid_password? "PASSWORD"
If it is not valid than maybe your problem is just with presenting the error message...

Comment: @ShiraElitzur password is valid